# Apache forces a trailing slash to 301

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

We use Apache (on Runcloud) behind Cloudflare to redirect links. It's done with .htaccess, as simple as possible.

```
Redirect 301 /advertiser/google https://google.com
```

For some reason Apache forces a trailing slash at the end of each redirect, and some URLs - namely those that should not contain trailing slash - will not work.

How do I config Apache to redirect exactly to the URL in .htaccess?

Comment: Apache does not by itself add trailing slashes. You omitted the part of the configuration that does it.

Comment: You need to describe the precise URLs that are getting a slash appended. Are you requesting _directories_ without a trailing slash? In which case, Apache will indeed append a slash (by default) - but this is correct behaviour. However, in your example, you are redirecting to `https://google.com` - however, that is not strictly valid and the _browser_ (not Apache) will effectively append a slash to the hostname in order to make the request valid (you can't have an entirely empty URl-path in a valid HTTP request).

Answer (score 2):

Please note: a HTTP 301 Redirect is "Moved Permanently" and as such will be cached by both web browsers, CDN's and proxy servers and after you have changed or removed the `Redirect` directive  you may still observe the effects of the old setting. You may need to test from a new anonymous browser window and/or clear your caches after each change.

Second: with the `Redirect` any path information beyond the pattern in the URL path you're redirecting will be appended to the target URL.

In other words: with a setting `Redirect 301 /advertiser/google https://google.com`   a request with a longer path `http://example.com/advertiser/google/more` should get redirected by Apache to `https://google.com/more`.

When a request for `http://example.com/advertiser/google` gets redirected to `https://google.com/` (with the added trailing slash) the most likely reason is that something in your configuration first appends that trailing slash and converts the request before the Redirect get applied.

You can bypass caching effects from both the cloud flare CDN and your own web browser and test your configuration by making requests directly to your webserver with a commandline client such as for instance :

```
 curl -v -H "Host: example.com" http://<real-IP-address-of-your-webserver>/advertiser/google
```

and compare that to

```
  curl -v http://example.com/advertiser/google
```

Comment: "...gets redirected to `https://google.com/` (with the added trailing slash)" - the _browser_ will effectively append the slash in this situation. (The slash here is the _start_ of the URL-path - the URL-path cannot be entirely empty). https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/35646/1243